# Как правильно выбрать окончание?

Tags: окончания

Как правильно: *Пункты будущего обвинения* или *Пункты будущему обвинению*?

Comment: 1. Добавляет пункты будущего обвинения 2. добавляет пункты будущему обвинению.

Comment: Поскольку «будущего», то уместнее говорить о Проекте обвинения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Правильно: добавить пункты к будущему обвинению.**

ДОБАВИТЬ,  св. что (чего). 1. = Прибавить Прибавить к уже имеющемуся, дополнить до необходимого, нужного. Д. краску в раствор. Д. сто рублей. Д. скорость. // Присоединить дополнительно к чему-л. Д. соль в суп. Д. сто рублей. // **Сказать или написать в дополнение; дополнить.** Д. несколько слов к письму. Д. что-л. к сказанному.

**Комментарий**

1) Родительный беспредложный не подойдёт, что видно из словаря.

2) Винительный с предлогом В не подходит по значению (мы именно присоединяем,  не добавляем до нужного/необходимого).

3) Дательный беспредложный  – это преимущественно **личный падеж** (обозначает одушевленного адресата – кому), исключением является определенная тематика (к примеру, соответствовать правилам, учить музыке), **поэтому добавить что-то (чему?) обвинению  мы не можем.**

**И вывод:** при ответе на вопросы желательно пользоваться словарем, точный ответ сложно дать только по слуху.

Answer (score 3):

1.Добавляет пункты (какие? чего?) будущего обвинения

2.Добавляет пункты ( куда? во что?) в будущее обвинение(лучше "в текст будущего обвинения")

3.Добавляет пункты (к чему?) к будущему обвинению (лучше "к тексту будущего обвинения")Или, как Вам предложили, к Проекту.